# Set query as a model and limit it further

Tags: python, sql, qt, model, pyqt

In my program, I use a sqlite database, with a table "papers". I have several `QTableviews` displaying the data contained in papers. One model per view. I initialize my model like this:

```
model.setTable("papers")
```

However, in each `QTableView`, I want to display only a sub-set of the data. This subset is determined by a sql query. Ex:

```
query = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
query.prepare("SELECT id FROM papers WHERE new=1")
query.exec_()
model.setQuery(query)
```

But then, if I want to perform ADDITIONAL queries on the subset (not on the entire model), it starts to become really complicated. So I wonder if there is a way to either:

- define a subset of data obtained trough a sql query as a model
- perform additional queries on a query

Ex:

After I selected all the items with new=1, I want all of them with liked=1.

Comment: You can create a temporary table.  However, in most cases, you can just add additional clauses to the `where` to get refinements.

Comment: Yes, but I would precisely like to avoid adding clauses to the where statement

Comment: You could use a proxy model to add the commands that you need.

Comment: Afaik you can filter a view in Qt as well as presenting different models with might come from different queries. I don't know what is better, I only know there are different possibilities for it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a QSqlTableview for each view. Add a model to each, just as you did. Add additional filtering to any table by adding for example

`model.setfilter(new=1);`

This filter results in a where clause in the underlying select.